# How to modify the gdm3 greeter's texts?

Tags: 18.04, gdm

I'd like to change, for example, the "Sorry, that didn't work" to something else. Are the texts of the gdm3 greeter available and modifiable somewhere in the system?

I am aware that this might cause problems if I need to debug my system in the future, since I can't use the defaut messages anymore. However, the default messages are so easily attainable that I don't see this as a problem.